# datepicker - unavailableDates from csv-file

Tags: jquery, csv, datepicker

I'm trying to get unavailable dates for my datepicker-calendar off a csv-file.

The csv-file structure looks like this:

```
26.08.2015
05.08.2015
```

My call for getting the data off the csv-file looks like this:

```
var unavailableDates = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://www.website.de/dates.csv",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) { 
                    console.log(data);
                    }
                    });

alert (unavailableDates);
```

The consolge-log outputs this:

```
26.08.2015
05.08.2015
```

But the alert-popup says:

```
[object Object]
```

So how can I get the data off the csv-correctly, I need these data in this structure:

```
var unavailableDates = ["19-8-2015","14-8-2015"];
```

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I managed the creating of the csv-file in the correct way with a hyphen instead of a dot, so the csv-structure now looks like this:

```
26-08-2015
05-08-2015
```

But I'm still getting

```
[object Object]
```

from the alert popup.

Comment: Can you examine the object? Alert popups aren't going to be very informative.  Use your web developer tools.

Comment: Hey @Marc, thanks for trying to help! I don't know exactly what you mean by that...I tried `alert (JSON.stringify(unavailableDates));`and get this output **{"readyState":1}...anything else I need to research on how to examine an object...my Chrome-developer-tools doesn't output anything else than the log like posted above in the console.

Comment: hm...I don't know...I tried `console.log(unavailableDates)` and I'm now getting some more information in the console-view. This seems to be pointing to the correct direction: `responseText: "05-08-2015↵07-08-2015↵26-08-2015↵"`...I guess I have to put this into an array somehow, and getting rid of the linebreaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/ for cvs to array.
since you are using Ajax callback function, you can only get the result inside success function. so what you can do is, create  another function which take the csv array as a parameter and call it inside success callback. check below code:

```
var unavailableDates = $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.website.de/dates.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                var csvArray= $.csv.toArray(data);
                processCsvArray(csvArray);
          }
});
function processCsvArray(csvData){
  //do your work
}
```

Comment: Thx for trying to help, @Manju! I tried this, but this lead to the same output **[object Object]**...so far I made some progress - I hope - by using this: `var unavailableDates = $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "http://www.website.de/dates.csv", dataType: "text", success: function(data) { myDate = data.replace(/\n/g, ','); console.log(myDate); }      });`which outputs this in the console: **05-08-2015,07-08-2015,26-08-2015,**...but I don't even know how to access **myDate** globally...and I still think I need an array, this is a string, isn't it? **dataType: "json"** creates no output in the log.

Comment: you need csv object to array converter. check this https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/ and call $.csv.toArrays(csv); on your success callback data.

Comment: ok, this helped, thx again! unless i hoped to not need to implement another script...but now I've got the output like I need it I guess: **["26-08-2015", "05-08-2015"]**...but I only can access it from within the `success: function(data) { myDate = data.replace(/\n/g, ','); var result = $.csv.toArray(myDate); console.log(result);`...when I try to access the variable _result_ "globally" from outside the function with `console.log(result)` I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined**.

Comment: Hey @EMEm Yes data will not be available outside the success callback. I have made changes to my original answer, if you found it useful and working, can you mark it answered please?

Comment: thx again Manju, much appreciation! with your edit I'm able to access the array within your new function. but I need the array to be accessible inside another function: `function unavailable(date) { dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" +date.getFullYear(); if ($.inArray(dmy, **unavailableDates**) < 0) { return [true,"","book"]; } else {
return [false,"","no booking possible"]; } }`...in this function **unavailableDates** must be replaced by **csvArray**...that's the goal I want to achieve.

Comment: I just realised that when I choose a date in the calender, the **unavailableDates** defined in the csv get disabled -so it's working somehow. That's is the function when this happens:  `onSelect: function(date) { var date = $(this).val(); $('input#date').val(date);`So can I "trigger" an onSelect on page-load?

Comment: I think i got it finally! A simple `async: false,`in my ajax-function did the trick. So with some editing of my other code that did not get posted here your answer lead me to the correct direction! Thanks again!